# Dump all DATABASE with specifi prefixe with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, backup

Im currently using the tool pg_dump to backup my database.

I have a lot of database. I don't know their full name but I know that all **DATABASES** have a well defined prefix.

I would like to automate the process of backup all my **DATABASES**, however, i have not found a way to specify pg_dump to dump multiple **DATABASE** that have the same prefix.

I said **database** and not table nor schema, because I tried the commands in the pgsql doc which gives the options -n for schemas and -t for tables.
But that's not what I want to do, I want to save all my databases with a defined prefix.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can only ever backup a single database with `pg_dump`. You can backup all databases with `pg_dumpall`. With `pg_dumpall`, you can only opt to exclude certain databases from the dump.

Comment: pg_basebackup could be another option to backup an entire cluster. But it depends on what type of backup your want. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html